# python configparser key error raised when using Globally

Tags: api, configparser, python-3.9

When I'm trying to pass the API endpoint values in the post API file, KeryError has unfortunately been raised. In the baseapi.ini file, I wrote [API] endpoint = value

Post API file:

```
import requests
from APIs.payLoad import addBookPayload
from Utilities.configration import config
from Utilities.resources import *

url = config()['API']['endpoint']+ApiResources.addBook
header = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

response = requests.post(url, json=addBookPayload("pl74"), headers=header,)
print(response.json())
response_json = response.json()
book_ID = response_json['ID']
```

Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Muhammad Azmul Haq\PycharmProjects\BackEndProject\APIs\PostAPI.py", line 8, in <module>
        url = config()['API']['endpoint']+ApiResources.addBook
      File "C:\Users\Muhammad Azmul Haq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\configparser.py", line 960, in __getitem__
        raise KeyError(key)
    KeyError: 'API'
```

Does anyone have an idea what I did wrong Kind regards?

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing your global variable in config before accessing it. Try assigning value in the current file,
or

Put all configure in the separate configuration file and import that configuration file.

Comment: I did the same steps but not resolved yet. When I use the directly base link(http//:__.__.__) instead of config()['API']['endpoint'] then works perfectly.